# Why my form need two (2) clicks to submit using jQuery Validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

Why my form need two clicks to submit using jQuery Validate?

```
contact_form.validate({ ... });
```

Demo: http://goo.gl/7jQjqY

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling

```
$(form).submit(function() {
   //
});
```

inside your `submitHandler` is incorrect: you are just adding the supplied function as an event handler for the form, but not actually calling it. So the first time you press the button, you are only *defining* a new event handler. The second press works because **now** that handler has been defined.

To fix, just remove the

```
$(form).submit(function() {
```

and corresponding

```
});
```

lines, putting your submit code directly in the `submitHandler` instead.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var str = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.mail.jsp',
        type : 'POST',
        data: str,
        //dataType : 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            // etc
        }
    });
}
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6dFWv/6/) – it's literally just yours with lines 37 and 57 commented out.